# How to use FirePHP-Core Dependency

Tags: php, laravel-4, composer-php, firephp

I've added [FirePHPCore](https://packagist.org/packages/firephp/firephp-core) to my composer.js dependencies and pulled them down, and installed the FirePHP Chrome plugin, but I still can't seem to log to Chrome's console.  I've only just started using Laravel and Composer, where previously I was using CodeIgniter and adding FirePHP as a third-party library. What else do you have to do to set up FirePHPCore in Laravel 4? Do I add it to autoload in Composer.json?

Answer (score 1):

Laravel uses [Monolog](https://github.com/Seldaek/monolog) to handle all its logging so you should probably investigate enabling the [FirePHPHandler](https://github.com/Seldaek/monolog/blob/master/src/Monolog/Handler/FirePHPHandler.php) for it in your bootstrap (somewhere like [app/filters.php](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/app/filters.php)).

```
App::before(function($request)
{
    // Get an instance of Monolog
    $monolog = Log::getMonolog();
    // Choose FirePHP as the log handler
    $monolog->pushHandler(new \Monolog\Handler\FirePHPHandler());
});
```

You can then log to it manually like this:

```
Log::info('info message');
Log::warning('warning message');
Log::error('error message');
```

Extra reading:

- http://www.codediesel.com/php/debuggin-laravel-with-monolog-and-firephp/
- http://www.laravel-tricks.com/tricks/log-queries-to-firephp-console-with-monolog
- http://www.codediesel.com/php/debuggin-laravel-with-monolog-and-firephp/